# Remove substring between parentheses in a string

Tags: c, string, strtok

I need to remove each substring between parentheses. I have found some solutions but none is good. Here is an example:

My string is: ***text(lorem(ipsum)abcd)pieceoftext*** and the actual output: ***lorem(ipsum***

However, the expected output: **text(())pieceoftext** or **textpieceoftext**

Here is the code. I've run out of ideas. I thought of using `strtok()` but I have two different delimiters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "text(lorem(ipsum)abcd)pieceoftext";
    const char *patternA = "(";
    const char *patternB = ")";
    char *target = NULL;
    char *start, *end;

    if (start = strstr( s, patternA ))
    {
        start += strlen( patternA);
        if (end = strstr( start, patternB ) )
        {
            target = (char *)malloc(end - start + 1);
            memcpy(target, start, end - start);
            target[end - start] = '\0';
        }
   }
   if (target)
      printf("Answer: %s\n", target);
   return 0;
}
```

Looking forward to hearing some of your ideas to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Why did you tag this as C++? I ask this because the C++ answer to your problem is VERY different than the C one.

Comment: Start with a simpler exercise. Do you know how to copy a string from one array to another (do not use built-in functions such as `strcpy` or `strlen`)? Do you know how to copy a string but leave out all `x`s (`"axbxc" -> "abc"`)? Do you know how to copy a string but leave out all instances of `x`, `y`, `z`?

Comment: Yes, I do know how to do this.

Comment: @VitaliyKalmyk OK, show me.

Comment: @melpomene
Should I post the code as an answer? I am new on Stackoverflow. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @VitaliyKalmyk Oh well, it's kind of too late now. You've already been given the solution with full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, just allocate enough memory to `target` as you need to hold the entire source string `s`, because you really have no idea how much space you will need.  Remember to add one for the end-of-string character.

Then change `patternA` and `patternB` from `char *` to just `char`, so you can compare them against individual chars in `s`.

Then you need to loop through the source string, keeping track of whether you are inside parentheses or not.  Since you need to support nested parentheses, I would use a counter of how deep inside the parentheses you are:

```
int main()
{
    const char *s = "text(lorem(ipsum)abcd)pieceoftext";
    const char patternA = '(';
    const char patternB = ')';
    char *target;
    int targetIndex = 0;
    int parenDepth = 0;

    target = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    // check for malloc() error

    for (int sourceIndex = 0; sourceIndex < strlen(s); sourceIndex++) {
        if (s[sourceIndex] == patternA) {
            // we are going deeper into parens, add to level, then ignore the char
            parenDepth++;
            continue;
        }

        if (s[sourceIndex] == patternB) {
            // we are coming out of the parens, lower our level, ignore the parens char
            parenDepth--;
            continue;
        }

        if (parenDepth == 0) {
            // if depth is 0, then we are not inside parens, so copy the char to target
            target[targetIndex++] = s[sourceIndex];
        }
    }

    // add end-of-string
    target[targetIndex] = '\0';

    printf("Answer: %s\n", target);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It really did the job done. I have one question. Is possible to reduce the code to using the functions from `string.h`
Just have been thinking about for a shorter code

Comment: Well, there is `strchr()` which lets you search a string for a specific `char`.  But you need to look out for both open and close parens, so you would probably need to use `strstr()` and look for "()".  I'd think you would do the same basic depth-counting and I really don't think it would be cleaner or shorter than this simple loop through the source string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you don't use `strtok`(`strtok_r`) only. I think it is more functional for this purpose. Just play with it somewhat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "text(lorem(ipsum)abcd)pieceoftext";
    char const * delim = ")(";
    char *token;
    char *rest = str;

    while ((token = strtok_r(rest, delim, &rest))) {
         printf("token: %s\n", token);
         printf("rest: %s\n", rest);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not account for the nesting of `()`.  With `strtok_r()`, information is lost as to what token was detected.  Further, OP had `const char *s = "text(lorem(ipsum)abcd)pieceoftext";` implying a solution that worked without changing the source string, like this one does.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate basic parsing techniques and use those to build a small sized program that does what you want.

```
hello(world)world
```

A simple solution:

If lookahead is an opening paren, stop saving. Until there is a closing paren. When there might be imbricated parens you just maintain a global variable of how *deep* we are (increment when there is an opening paren and decrement when there is a closing paren). When this variable is zero you can save.

You can use the same pattern beforehand to check if there are enough closing parens.

Comment: And by "global constant", you mean local variable?

Comment: @melpomene you know what ? I am sorry